# How to get starting time of session in CakePHP?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I need to know when current session started.
I can store that value like this:

```
$this->Session->write('sessionStartTime', time());
```

But at what point should I add this code to CakePHP 2.4.6 ?
Should I add to AppController's beforeFilter() or is there a better place to put it ?
Or does CakePHP gives session start time ?

Edit:
Also there is a low level solution like this.
But I don't prefer because it depends to the session store type.

```
$timestamp = filemtime( TMP.'sessions'.DS.'sess_'.session_id() );
```

Comment: why don't add it in your login action !

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: @ndm I'm sorry. Version 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

`Session.timeout` - The number of minutes before CakePHP’s session handler expires the session. This affects Session.autoRegenerate (below), and is handled by CakeSession.[please visit the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html)

and cookies

the `Session.cookieTimeout` value. Although the php session was still valid, the expiration date on the session cookie does not get refreshed

Comment: Session timeout isn't important for me. I only need to know when session started.

Answer (score 0):

The start time of the current session is available via [**`CakeSession::$time`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakeSession.html#$time). It will be `false` until the session has been started.